# If you land on an ally space, but no ally is available, what happens?

Tags: super-mario-party

If you land on an ally space or use an ally phone, but all the available characters are already taken by other players, what happens?

Example: If all 4 players have 3 allies each (with no unlockable characters unlocked) and I land on an ally space, what happens?

My guess is that if fizzes out, and nothing happens, but I can't know without having the game where you always land on allies spaces. Got close once (there were only 2-3 allies left) but never got to a game where all allies were taken.

Comment: My assumption is that you just couldn't get an ally. If I ever come across that situation, I'll be sure to respond here with a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Caps at 4, if you land on the space after that, the game tells you that you have enough allies.

More info: If you land on an Ally Space, your ally list is full but there is one available, you can boot an ally out of your party and select a new one.

Comment: Allright, but a situation could happen when playing a game with no extra characters are unlocked where a player has space for a new ally, but the game doesn't have any to give. There's 16 base characters, 4 are used for players, so you need all players to have 3 allies. You then have no unused allies, and everybody has space for another. Thats the situation I'm asking about (but still thanks for your answer, was about to ask if there's a max number of allies before the game blocks you)